# Uniform convergence over $[0,1]$ preserves zeroes proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Our teacher gave this problem in class and said that the hint to solve this was by using triangle inequality.

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous real-valued functions on $[0,1]$ converging uniformly on $[0.1]$ to a function $f$. Suppose for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $x_n \in [0,1]$ such that $f_n(x_n) = 0$. Show that there exists $x \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x) = 0$.

But I feel, we don't really need the triangle inequality here.

By definition, for every $\epsilon >0,$ $ \exists$ $ N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that  $n \geq N$ implies $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \epsilon $ $\forall$ $x \in [0,1]$.

Specifically, for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists$ $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that  $n \geq N$ implies $|f_n(x_n) - f(x_n)| \leq \epsilon$.

So, by given information $|f(x_n)| < \epsilon$. And since $f([0,1])$ must be closed, there must exist $x \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x) = 0$.

Can anyone please let me know if my proof is correct ?

If not, where is the fallacy ?

Comment: That last sentence is not clear to me. It rather seems that you want $x$ to be a limit point of $(x_n)$ and use the continuity of $f$. At least I don't see how $f([0,1])$ being closed helps here.

Comment: @nejimban Since $f([0,1])$ is a closed set, since $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):f(x_n)\in f([0,1])$, and since $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=0$, $0\in f([0,1])$. In other words, there is some $x\in[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. To me it felt more natural to use the compactness of $[0,1]$ and introduce a limit point of $(x_n)$.

Comment: "So, by given information $|f(x_n)| < \epsilon$."  Problem: Which $n$ is this talking about?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet $n \geq N$ as specified in the line above. OP, your proof works, although you may want to add a little more detail, such as that you conclude that $0$ is a limit point of $f([0,1])$ and therefore that $0 \in f([0,1])$ since $f([0,1])$ is closed.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I will do that.